# How can I re-install removed packages on Solaris-10?

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris

My Solaris 10 SPARC host ran its pre-installed Apache server. After it failed to cooperate (it and I couldn't find my apxs) with the installation of mod_wsgi (to handle Django) I made the decision to uninstall this Apache instance and install an Apache instance that could handle mod_wsgi out of the box. I issued the command: pkgrm SUNWapchr SUNWapchu SUNWapchd.

I've since realized that uninstalling these packages was a mistake, and have found my apxs.

My problem is that I can not find a resource from which I can re-install these three packages.

According to docs.oracle.com, if I had the Solaris CD ROM, this should do the trick:

*pkgadd -d Solaris-product-directory SUNWapchr SUNWapchu SUNWapchd*

I do not have access to a Solaris CD.

Official question: Where might I find a repository of SUNW.* packages, online or on my system?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris 10 did not have an online package repository for the OS packages - you'll need to [download the Solaris 10 install images from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html) and mount the iso or burn it to DVD to get at the package contents.   Solaris 11 (including its OpenSolaris and Solaris Express predecessors) is the first Solaris release with an online package repo for the OS packages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community supported packages available at http://www.opencsw.org/.